# Laravel Custom Validation Order

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I add a custom Validation Rule

```
Validator::extend('validate_timezone', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $items = request('items');
    $from_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['from_date']);
    // my code below depend on $from_date
    ......
    ......

    return true;
);
```

validation rule

```
 "from_date" => "required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|validate_timezone",
```

The problem, custom validation `validate_timezone` run before `'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'`, so if the format of date is wrong, I will get error inside `validate_timezone` function

How can I force to validate `date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s` before the custom validation `validate_timezone`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) the following can be found:

> Rules will be validated in the order they are assigned.

Meaning the code is working as expected.
You're probably looking for the `bail` option:

> Sometimes you may wish to stop running validation rules on an attribute after the first validation failure. To do so, assign the `bail` rule to the attribute

Which would mean you should try this:

```
"from_date" => "bail|required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|validate_timezone",
```

Comment: `validate_timezone` always run before `'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'`

Comment: No it does not, but even if `'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'` fails, the other rules will still be called to see if they fail as well.

Comment: `"from_date" => "bail|required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|validate_timezone",`
i tried it,not working

Comment: you are right,Thank you,`'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'` runs before `validate_timezone` ,i was get error because in `validate_timezone` i iterates on all items from request and  do proccess on from_date,so i thought `validate_timezone` runs first, i gets error because i use values not validated yet in `validate_timezone`